# Google sign in + navigation with jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, google-oauth, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am trying to shift from java+xml style android development to kotlin jetpack compose.

I am trying to figure out how to move all my google sign in logic from the main activity to a new LoginScreen composable, this process seems very taxing since google sign in requires many activity references such as registerForActivityResult, what is the way to call all these activity references from a composable screen.

My google sign in functionality works well. But I am unsure of how to integrate navigation in this piece of code

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
    private lateinit var signInLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        val account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        if (account != null) {
//            System.out.println("launching intent to next page");
//            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserHomeActivity.class);
//            startActivity(intent);
            account.getEmail()?.let { Log.d("Signed In: ", it) };
        } else {
            Log.d("Signed In: ", "Not signed in");
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val gso =
            GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build()

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(
            this,
            gso
        ) // since googleApiClient is deprecated, have to use workaround


        signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult(),
            ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> { result ->
                val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> =
                    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.getData())
                handleSignInResult(task)
            })

        setContent {

            var username by remember{mutableStateOf<String>("")}

            MeauComposeTheme {

                Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                    , horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    val context = LocalContext.current

                    Button(
                        onClick = {
                            //startForResult.launch(googleSignInClient?.signInIntent)
                                  signIn()
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Signed in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()

                            val account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context);
                            if (account != null) username = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context)?.displayName.toString() else username = "not found"


                        },

                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 10.dp),
                            //.height(100.dp)
                            //.padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                            backgroundColor = Color.Black,
                            contentColor = Color.White
                        )
                    ) {
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icons8_google),
                            contentDescription = ""
                        )
                        Text(text = "Sign in with Google", modifier = Modifier.padding(6.dp))
                    }
                    Button(
                        onClick = {
                            //startForResult.launch(googleSignInClient?.signInIntent)
                            signOut()
                            username = "anonymous"
                        },

                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            //.height(100.dp)
                            .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                            backgroundColor = Color.Black,
                            contentColor = Color.White
                        )
                    ) {
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icons8_google),
                            contentDescription = ""
                        )
                        Text(text = "Sign out", modifier = Modifier.padding(6.dp))
                    }
                    Text(text = "$username", fontSize = 30.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun signIn() {
        println("void sign in")
        val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
        signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
        println("got sign in intent")
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        try {
            val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            val idToken = account.idToken
//            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, UserHomeActivity::class.java)
//            startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            Log.w("Sign In Error", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun signOut() {
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) {
                Log.d("Signed Out: ", "Successful")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Signed out successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
    }

}
```

I tried creating a LoginScreen composable file and copy pasted all the sign in logic into that file however I was not able to reference the contexts required for the toasts in the functions such as signOut() and handleSignInResult().

Also now that my logic was no longer under the OnCreate method, i was also unable to call registerForActivityResult(), can someone please suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem in this code was the building of the sign in launcher from the compose screen.

The solution to the problem is to build the signInLauncher in the main activity file and simply pass it to the LoginScreen as arguments,

Also, the issue in calling context in the signIn, signOut and handleSignInResult functions were solved in a similar fashion by declaring the contexts and passing them as arguments to the functions

The code for Login screen composable can by given as

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient, signInLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>) {

    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
//    lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
//    lateinit var signInLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
    var context: Context = LocalContext.current

    MeauComposeTheme {

        var username by remember { mutableStateOf<String>("") }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            val context = LocalContext.current

            Button(
                onClick = {
                    //startForResult.launch(googleSignInClient?.signInIntent)
                    signIn(mGoogleSignInClient,signInLauncher)
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Signed in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()

                    val account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context);
                    if (account != null) username =
                        GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context)?.displayName.toString() else username =
                        "not found"


                },

                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 10.dp),
                //.height(100.dp)
                //.padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Black,
                    contentColor = Color.White
                )
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icons8_google),
                    contentDescription = ""
                )
                Text(text = "Sign in with Google", modifier = Modifier.padding(6.dp))
            }
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    //startForResult.launch(googleSignInClient?.signInIntent)
                    signOut(context,mGoogleSignInClient)
                    username = "anonymous"
                },

                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    //.height(100.dp)
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Black,
                    contentColor = Color.White
                )
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icons8_google),
                    contentDescription = ""
                )
                Text(text = "Sign out with Google", modifier = Modifier.padding(6.dp))
            }
            Text(text = "$username", fontSize = 30.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        }
    }

}

fun signIn(mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient,signInLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>) {
    println("void sign in")
    val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
    signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
    println("got sign in intent")
}

fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>, context: Context) {
    try {
        val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        val idToken = account.idToken
//            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, UserHomeActivity::class.java)
//            startActivity(intent)
    } catch (e: ApiException) {
        Log.w("Sign In Error", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}


fun signOut(context: Context, mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient) {
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
        .addOnCompleteListener(
            //context.mainExecutor
        ) {
            Log.d("Signed Out: ", "Successful")
            Toast.makeText(context, "Signed out successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }
}
```

The code for main activity can be given as:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
    private lateinit var signInLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        val account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        if (account != null) {
//            System.out.println("launching intent to next page");
//            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserHomeActivity.class);
//            startActivity(intent);
            account.getEmail()?.let { Log.d("Signed In: ", it) };
        } else {
            Log.d("Signed In: ", "Not signed in");
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val gso =
            GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build()

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(
            this,
            gso
        ) // since googleApiClient is deprecated, have to use workaround


        signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> { result ->
                val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> =
                    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.getData())
                handleSignInResult(task)
            })

        setContent {
            LoginScreen(mGoogleSignInClient,signInLauncher)
        }
    }




}
```